Intellimize GA4 data in BigQuery
I'm working in integrating Intellimize with Google Analytics. We have in place a GA4 BigQuery export. How test assignment data will appear in BigQuuery? In the existing events table? And where these columns will be found? As event params?
experienceId, experienceName, experienceType, variationId, variationName, ccStatus


Hi, the question is not clear to me , you want to  backfill data in the previous created table  OR recently you created GA4 to BQ and  want to transfer data using custom schema, not default schema . Can you clarify more with example ?
